# how to fix ValueError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, index-error

I keep getting this error:

line 23, in encode
    raw_out[i][pos] = message[pos]
IndexError: list index out of range

for this part of the program:

```
def encode(message: str, key: int) -> str:
"""
Encode text using Rail-fence Cipher.

Replace all spaces with '_'.

:param message: Text to be encoded.
:param key: Encryption key.
:return: Decoded string.
"""
message = message.replace(" ", "_")

down = True
raw_out = []
out = ''
i = 0
for x in range(key):
    raw_out.append({})
for pos in range(len(message)):
    raw_out[i][pos] = message[pos]
    if i == key - 1:
        down = False
    if i == 0:
        down = True
    if down:
        i = i + 1
    else:
        i = i - 1
for p in raw_out:
    for q in p:
        out += p[q]
return out
```

I'm not sure how to fix the error. Any ideas?

Comment: For what value of message and int are you getting the error. Can you provide a test case.

Comment: print(encode("hello", 1))  # => hello

Comment: Hey Ants. Please undelete your Code Review request. I had written up a rather large review, and would prefer it not go to waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When key is one or when the key is bigger than the length of the string return the string as it is. Doesn't make sense to do any processing.

right after the line

```
message = message.replace(" ", "_")
```

you can check for the condition

```
if key == 1 or key > len(message):
    return message
```

Comment: How does one fix that